# How to check if field on desktop application is empty or filled, and if it's filled mark as exception, and if it's empty proceed?

Tags: if-statement, rpa, uipath, uipath-studio, uipath-robot

I am new to UI path and am trying to build a workflow/sequence to check if a field in my desktop application is filled or not.

If the field is empty then I want to proceed with the process, and if it is filled I want it to be marked as an exception.

I currently have it so the flow goes as follows:
1. Identified element
2. used Text Exists activity for that field, and I inputed "" as the Text

What are the next steps?

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you used **Get Text** command, and using if condition, check if the text is null or empty and take action.

Answer (score 0):

First you want to use Get text on the Text box to extract its contents and store this in a variable in UiPath (Note: if you create the variable from the side properties panel it will give it the type `GenericValue`, you'll want to change this to `String`)

Next depends an what you mean by filled:

If you want to accept spaces as been filled then you can use  `String.IsNullOrEmpty(YOUR_VARIABLE)`

If you want the filed to be filled with characters that aren't spaces you can use
`String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(YOUR_VARIABLE)`

for your exception it will depend on weather you want to throw it as an

- Application exception (`new System.Exception("EXCEPTION MESSAGE")`)

or

- Businessexception (`new UiPath.Core.BusinessRuleException("EXCEPTION MESSAGE")`)

So your workflow will want to look something like this
[image]